# Rmarkdown (html): local search for table of contents (toc)

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, tableofcontents

I was wondering if Rmarkdown for html outputs has a function that can do a local search for the TOC only. I don't want to use the Ctrl+F function as I have got repeated words used as the section names and it would be much slower than just searching over the TOC.

Answer (score -1):

The TOC is built using [Tocify.js](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.tocify.js/). It does not have any such feature, so don't expect anything in RMarkdown unless you cook one up using JQuery/Javascript.

Comment: thanks so much but I don't have much experience in Java cripes unfortunately. For the moment, I guess for R users shiny app might be the solution.